# Comparing Text with Text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Example : i have a "output.txt" file. it contains the word "hello"

i need to compare that output.txt file with a stored variable.

my program,

```
@echo off
cls
set /p a=hello
set /p b=<output.txt
if %a%==%b% goto ONE
:TWO 
echo not equal
pause
exit
:ONE 
echo equal
pause
exit
```

I expected output to be equal if output.txt = %a%
or output to be not equal if output.txt ≠ %a%

But i didn't get correct output What i expect.. Please help me guys.. Please..

Comment: instead of `set /p a=hello` you probably want `set a=hello` (without `/p`, as you don't want to ask the user for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will return "equal" if the content of %A% is found in c:\temp\output.txt

```
@echo off
set A=hello

FindStr "\<%A%\>" C:\temp\output.txt >NUL &&  (
  echo equal
) || (
  echo not equal
)
pause
```